# Calling an API asynchronously java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I am looping through a list of IDs and doing a look up to get objects. I'm new to multi threading, is there a way to handle this without using parallel streams?

```
private List<MyObject> lookupById(List<String> ids) {
  List<MyObject> myObjs = new ArrayList<>();

  for(String id : ids) {
    myObjs.add(apiService.lookUp(id));
  }

  return myObjs;
}
```

Comment: Why not use parallel streams?

Comment: Can parallel streams scale well for things that might end up taking a while? Just because I'm making calls to the db, I figured that parallel streams would be dangerous in these situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm thinking:

```
private List<MyObject> lookupById(List<String> ids) {

    List<MyObject> myObjs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(ids.size());
    ids.forEach(e -> {

        new Thread(() -> {

            myObjs.add(apiService.lookUp(e));
            countDownLatch.countDown();

        }).start();

    });

    try{
        countDownLatch.await();
    }catch(Exception ignored){}

    return myObjs;

}
```

Also there can be other ways.

Comment: No join or anything, you're just going to return an empty list?

Comment: @matt join? It not return an empty list. `myObjs.add(apiService.lookUp(e));` in `Thread` implementation.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know how long 'lookUp' takes. Creating a thread and calling start can be very quick. So can return myObjs before any items have been added to it. That also means it will be getting modified after it has been returned.

Comment: @matt I updated it. But now, I'm not sure if it's the best way. Because can ends with an infinite loop. It depends by what happen in `apiService.lookUp`. But thank you for you observation. I omitted it.

Comment: You could use a [CountdownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) Then you don't need to create a busy loop.

Comment: @matt , Updated

Comment: Thanks, this definitely does the trick, is there any concerns if my list size gets really large? Like in the hundred thousands?

Comment: @Spider If the processor don't have problems. If you have problems, I think you can split in small lists.

Comment: @Spider yes, you don't need to make a thread per task, you can have each thread process multiple tasks. If you use an executor service, that manages the threads for you. [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) is a convenience class for creating executor services with different options.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with an executor service.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
List<Future<MyObject>> futures = ids.stream().map( 
                                     pool.sumbit( 
                                         id->apiService.lookUp(id) 
                                     ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
List<MyObject> myObjs = futures.stream().map( f -> { 
                                                     try { 
                                                         f.get();
                                                     } catch (Exception e){         
                                                         return null;
                                                     }
                                             ).collect( Collectors.toList());
```

This keeps the order of the list. Otherwise the thread version might be sufficient. I don't know why you wouldn't just use a parallel stream.

The advantages this has over the accepted solution.

- The list is in the same order.
- If there is an exception, null gets added instead of never finishing.
- Doesn't create an unlimited number of threads. Only creates 'N' which should be a reasonable number.